# Difference between the past date time and current time in minutes in golang

Tags: date, go, time

I have current time and past time, Im trying to findout difference in minutes.

Here is my code im trying, although im new to go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //fetching current time
    currentTime := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    //past time comes in as string
    pasttimestr := "2018-10-10 23:00"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    //converting string to date
    pasttime, err := time.Parse(layout, pasttimestr)
        if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //differnce between pastdate and current date
    diff := currentTime.Sub(pasttime)
    fmt.Println("difference time in min : ", diff)
}
```

Error:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\dates.go:21:21: currentTime.Sub undefined (type string has no field or method Sub)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: updated question with error kosa

Comment: The `.Format()` function returns a string representation of the datetime, not a `Time` struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably remove the format function call from current time to get the actual time struct rather than a string representation and and fix the layout for past time

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //fetching current time
    currentTime := time.Now()
    loc := currentTime.Location()
    //past time comes in as string
    pasttimestr := "2018-10-10 23:00"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04"
    //converting string to date
    pasttime, err := time.ParseInLocation(layout, pasttimestr, loc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Past Time: ", pasttime)
    fmt.Println("Current Time: ", currentTime)
    //differnce between pastdate and current date
    diff := currentTime.Sub(pasttime)
    fmt.Printf("time difference is %v or %v in minutes\n", diff, diff.Minutes())
}
```

Gives me

```
Past Time:  2018-10-10 23:00:00 -0400 EDT
Current Time:  2018-10-10 14:31:34.865259 -0400 EDT m=+0.000351797
time difference is -8h28m25.134741s or -508.41891235 in minutes
```

Comment: for me it is displaying:Past Time:  2018-10-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
Current Time:  2018-10-10 23:47:19.3722015 +0530 IST m=+0.005323000
time difference is 4h42m40.6277985s or 282.677129975 in minutes

Comment: it should be 48minutes

Comment: Looks like reverting the pasttime and current time was a mistake, actually. I have updated the code and output.

Comment: The reason you get 4+ hours is because your "past time" does not have a time zone, so it assumes that the time is in UTC

Comment: how can we convert the same in IST format? Any idea?

Comment: Updated code and output. Now it parses the past time as the same zone as current time.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `.Format()` function call on `time.Now()` like below. Also I've updated the `layout string` to match the format for `pasttimestr`.

```
func main() {
    //fetching current time
    currentTime := time.Now()
    //past time comes in as string
    pasttimestr := "2018-10-10 23:00"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04"
    //converting string to date
    pasttime, err := time.Parse(layout, pasttimestr)
        if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //differnce between pastdate and current date
    diff := currentTime.Sub(pasttime)
    fmt.Println("difference time is : ", diff)
}
```

**Output**

```
difference time is :  -4h36m32.001213s
```

Comment: why it is showing in negative. It should show something like 40m (eg: 40 minutes)

Comment: @btcuser I was running this on https://play.golang.org/ but I've updated the answer to reflect the output on my machine in the PDT timezone. As for the negative value, that's correct since it's currentTime sub pastTime.